# Deploy app sync by using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

Hi there I am trying to deploy AppSync using a serverless framework
but every time I get an error

Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying app sync-lambda-demo to stage dev (us-east-1)
Warning: Invalid AppSync Configuration:
at app sync: must be the object

```
× Stack app sync-lambda-demo-dev failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: win32, node 16.14.2, framework 3.30.1 (local) 3.30.1v (global), plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'schema')
    at getAppSyncConfig (C:\projects\lifescore-platform-latest\6\lambda\bitbucket\serverless-test2\Avallano bitbucket Account\getting-started\getting-started-with-graphql-and-app sync-with-python-main\lab2\node_modules\serverless-app sync-plugin\lib\getAppSyncConfig.js:45:35)"
```

this is my serverless code

```
useDotenv: true

service: ${env:SERVICE_NAME}

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: AWS
  runtime: python3.7
  memorize: 512
  timeout: 600
  architecture: x86_64
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  stackTags:
    product: soumilshah
    env: qa
    created-date: 2022-04-26
    team: python-dev
    customer-impact: false
    terraform: false

plugins:
  - serverless-appsync-plugin

package:
  exclude:
    - '**/*'
  include:
    - '*.py'


custom:
  appSync:
    name: "myApis"
    schema:
      - "schema.graphql"
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    mappingTemplates:
      - type: Query
        request: false
        response: false
        dataSource:  ${env:LAMBDA_SOURCE}
        field: getUsers
    dataSources:
      - type: AWS_LAMBDA
        name: ${env:LAMBDA_SOURCE}
        description: 'Lambda DataSource'
        config:
          lambdaFunctionArn: arn:aws:lambda:${env:REGION}:${env:ACCOUNT}:function:${env:SERVICE_NAME}-${opt:stage, 'dev'}-lambda


functions:
  lambda:
    handler: lambda_function.getUsers
```

this is a schema file

```
type Message {
    userId: Int!
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    completed: Boolean!
}

type Query {
    getUsers: Message!
}
```

this is my .env file

```
SERVICE_NAME=appsync-lambda-demo
REGION=us-east-1
ACCOUNT=58633912112
LAMBDA_SOURCE=Lambda_Data_Source
STAGE=dev
```

I tried many ways but was not able to find a solution

Comment: I have simmilar issue seems like moveing appSync to the root helped me, so except of `custom:` then `appSync:` I just have `appsync`. 
Then it seems to have other issues with config schema like `authentication` object except of `authenticationType` so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Indeed new version (>2.0.0) has been moved to the root. [plugin github readme](https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin)

Comment: Yeah they also have a upgrade guide to it
https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin/blob/master/doc/upgrading-from-v1.md